# Airgap Openshift cluster requires image registry

Tags: openshift

I have an airgapped installaion of openshift cluster. It was installed from a registry, that holds a copy of images from Redhat registry. The problem is, that after the installation, if this registry is not up, cluster does not start. Why does it need it during startup? Anyway to remove this dependency?

Thank you.